# workflow designer 2010 - associate workflow to a list

Tags: workflow, list, sharepoint-designer

i'm using sharepoint designer 2010.
I have created simlpe workflow from the designer.

now I want to associate this workflow to specific list (sharepoint custom list).
I do not find the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Example]
First you should deploy custom list to solution if list isn't deployed. After that read  [this(2007)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/assign-a-to-do-item-in-a-workflow-HA010233623.aspx) or [this (2010)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx)

Comment: thank for yor answer! But the "Associate to List" button inaccessible for me. (the button appears in the grey color, like the "Save as Template" button in your screen shot)

Comment: what do yo meen when you are say "deploy custom list"? to create custom list and save it?

Comment: I assume that you are not admin or at least contributor to your site collection. Give yourself appropriate rights (Open your SP site in web browser, navigate "Site Actions-Site Settings-Site collection administrators") and it should work ok. Related do "deploy custom list" answer is yes :)

Comment: Another possibility is that you create workflow which can't be hooked to list: On that you influence in the first steps while you design workflow.

Comment: @liron - can you please confirm my answer as correct, if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

On the left navigation panel, click on Workflows. Up on the ribbon, in the Save group, click on Save and then click on Publish. You should then see your workflow showing up in your list.